# Yii2 Auto login after registration

Tags: php, authentication, yii2

How can I achieve auto login after registration in yii2? In yii1, we achieved this through user Identity, but now I couldn't find it.

**MY controller**

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new User();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {
         Yii::$app->session->setFlash('success', 'Please Login with Email/Password!');

        return $this->redirect('../site/login');
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

If registration is successful, I want to auto login instead of going site login.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

    \Yii::$app->user->login($model);

   return $this->redirect(['/site/index']);

}
```

Comment: I din't use this method because it actually calls the `swichIdentity()` for do the login (and i don't know if the OP wants that logs count with this forced login), i rather use `swichIdentity()`. But I think it is a matter of opinion :P

Comment: sure you can use `switchIdentity` instead of `login` but I think `login` is more understood

Answer (score 2):

You can accomplish that with [switchIdentity()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-user.html#switchIdentity()-detail) method.

Example:

```
if ($userModel->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $userModel->save()) {
    Yii::$app->user->switchIdentity($userModel); // log in
    // do your stuff
}
```